# Difference In ChainIDs When Running NodEOS - Am I Connected To Mainnet?

Tags: mainnet

I noticed my server throws this ChainID:

```
chain_id":"cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f"
```

When I run

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_info
```

Now in another working app I saw the chainID listed as:

```
 chainId: 'aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906',
```

Could someone explain the differences and am I already connected to mainnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a genesis.json**

```
{
  "initial_timestamp": "2018-06-08T08:08:08.888",
  "initial_key": "EOS7EarnUhcyYqmdnPon8rm7mBCTnBoot6o7fE2WzjvEX2TdggbL3",
  "initial_configuration": {
    "max_block_net_usage": 1048576,
    "target_block_net_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_net_usage": 524288,
    "base_per_transaction_net_usage": 12,
    "net_usage_leeway": 500,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_num": 20,
    "context_free_discount_net_usage_den": 100,
    "max_block_cpu_usage": 200000,
    "target_block_cpu_usage_pct": 1000,
    "max_transaction_cpu_usage": 150000,
    "min_transaction_cpu_usage": 100,
    "max_transaction_lifetime": 3600,
    "deferred_trx_expiration_window": 600,
    "max_transaction_delay": 3888000,
    "max_inline_action_size": 4096,
    "max_inline_action_depth": 4,
    "max_authority_depth": 6
  }
}
```

Start EOS with

```
./nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --plugin eosio::http_plugin --http-server-address=127.0.0.1:8888 --http-validate-host=false --genesis-json genesis.json
```

If you still have previous instances running:

```
pkill -9 cleos
pkill -9 nodeos
pkill -9 keosd
```

Answer (score 0):

The chain id you are getting is based on with which network you are connected
For example i am connected with **mainnet** so i am getting

```
"chain_id" "aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906"
```

If i am connected with Jungletestnet then i get this chain id

```
"chain_id": "e70aaab8997e1dfce58fbfac80cbbb8fecec7b99cf982a9444273cbc64c41473"
```

And if you are connected with your own local private net then you are getting different chain id than both of above ids.

This id differs on your connection with nodes you ensure this ids by hitting on different api endpoints.